# Access Modifier of top class and class member

Tags: java

The topmost class can be public or default. And member level can be public, private, default or protected. If the topmost class is default then I do not understand what the use of member being public or protected?
For example

```
class Test {
  int a; // default access
  public int b; // public access
  private int c; // private access
  }
```

In this class, test access will be the default then what the use/mean of declaring its member as public.

Comment: This is just something that isn't prevented by the language spec, even if it serves no purpose. Sometimes you do have to use public in a package private class, e.g. methods in class implementing an interface; I would guess it would just be too bothersome to restrict other cases.

Comment: Top level access specifier is using to specify the acces of other elements in the package.